# Python Event.set() from one process to Event.is_set() in another

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i am currently trying to use the observer package in python to survey the changes brought to a folder, however i want to have a timer which resets everytime changes happen within the folder, or ends the processes when it times out. the timer and observer each run in a separate processes, when an event is sent from the oberver to reset the timer, i expect the timer to catch the `recount.set` to reset, however it doesn't seem to react to it

```
recount = multiprocessing.Event()

def run():
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        global recount
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        else :
            recount.set()

def timer(finish_state):
    global recount
    t = TimerReset(30.0)
    t.start()
    while not t.finished.is_set():
        if recount.is_set():
            print(recount.is_set())
        if recount.is_set() :
            t.reset()
            t.start
            recount.clear()
    finish_state.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finish_state = multiprocessing.Event()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer, args=(finish_state,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    finish_state.wait()
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
```

am i missing a detail conscerning events?

Comment: This will only work in linux (sharing an `Event` by simply defining it at the module level, and using `global`) you should instead explicitly pass the event to your `Process` as an argument. On Windows and MacOS, each process will end up with it's own unique `Event` object which is not connected to the others (this is a "Spawn" vs "Fork" behavior)

Comment: I see, thank you for this clarification, i also had to remove `@staticmethod` to access the event using `self` within the class method